# Have PowerShell and Windows PowerShell use the same profile.ps1

Tags: powershell

Windows 11 of course comes with Windows PowerShell.

I've also installed PowerShell 7.9.3.

I'd like for them both to use the same `profile.ps1`.

`$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` for Windows PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.2428
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.2428
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\Users\dharm> $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts
C:\Users\dharm\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
PS C:\Users\dharm>
```

`$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` for PowerShell 7.9.3:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.9
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.9
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

PS C:\Users\dharm> $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts
C:\Users\dharm\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
```

## Approach

I created a file `C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\PowerShellProfile.ps1`:

```
# Example function from profile.ps1. Other contents go here as needed.

function Recent ()
{
    Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 15
}
```

Then I source this file from the PowerShell profile:

```
. C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\PowerShellProfile.ps1
```

As well as the Windows PowerShell profile:

```
. C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\PowerShellProfile.ps1
```

## Question

This seems to work fine.

Is this the recommended approach? Is there a simpler method?

I used to have the Windows PowerShell profile simply source the PowerShell profile, but I had run into issues with that approach. Windows PowerShell would take a long time to start; it seems it was in a loop.